# Connection String Encryption is throwing error in command prompt

Tags: connectionstring

We have a requirement of encrypting the connection string of a Sitecore application with some external database entries in `connectionstring.config` file. We are using the below command to perform this operation-

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>Aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Encryption"
```

Where `C:\Encryption` is our path of the website root. but we are getting below error while running this command -

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
> Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> Encrypting configuration section...
> An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (D:\temp\test\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config)
>
> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. Failed!

[image]

how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigating, I found that Sitecore's Connection string uses a `configBuilders` attribute.

```
<connectionStrings configBuilders="SitecoreConnectionStringsBuilder">
 ......
</connectionStrings>
```

The encryption command tries to resolve this `configBuilders` on the on-premise server, to fix this issue, we need to remove this attribute with value (**configBuilders="SitecoreConnectionStringsBuilder"**) before performing the encryption command. So our connection string should be like the below -

```
<connectionStrings>
 ......
</connectionStrings>
```